# Arcobjects 10.3 C#: How to re activate the datasource of an ILayer, in memory

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I captured (stopped) a Layer (featureclass) from being deleted from the Table of contents of arcmap. When i re-add it back, the datasource is broken.

(See question :[Using ArcObjects to stop items from being deleted from Table of Contents?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175530/using-arcobjects-to-stop-items-from-being-deleted-from-table-of-contents))

I'm wondering what I need to cast my ILayer object to, in order to just activate the datasource?

The workspace is sde, but i find it odd that if the whole object(layer) is available when caught by the itemdeleted handlers, why is the datasource off?

I'm having trouble finding the right interface to use.

---

Here is the code that I have implemented: It readds the layer back to the ToC but the connection is not connected.
(`Exten` is the Addin.extension object for the addin.)

```
 public void On_TOCItemDeleted(object Item)
        {
            IWorkspaceName workspace;
            var msgText = "You tried to delete an item from the TOC.";

        // check that the item is of type ILayer (lyr file, raster, etc) before doing anything.
        var DeletedLayer = Item as ILayer;

        if (DeletedLayer == null)
            throw new Exception("Not iLayer file");

        IDataLayer2 src = DeletedLayer as IDataLayer2;
        var groupname = FindParentGroup(DeletedLayer.Name);

        if (src.DataSourceName != null)
        {
            workspace = (src.DataSourceName as IDatasetName).WorkspaceName;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (groupname)
            {
                case BLayerName: // basemaps etc
                    workspace = DeletedLayer.SetLayerSDEConnection(Exten.Analysis_WIP);
                    break;

                default: //analysis connection
                    workspace = DeletedLayer.SetAnalysisSDEConnection(Exten.Analysis_WIP);
                    break;
            }
        }
        src.Connect((workspace as IName));
        msgText = string.Format("You tried to delete the layer '{0}'. This operation was stopped.", DeletedLayer.Name);
        //Read the item

        var grouplyr = GetGroupByName(ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.Layers, groupname);

        grouplyr.Add(src as ILayer);

        ArcMap.Document.UpdateContents();
        ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.Refresh();

        Exten.InformUser("App", msgText);
    }
```

Comment: can you show some code? What is the workspace type?

Comment: Cast the layer to `IDatalayer2`.  Maybe the DataSourceName is still populated, and you can just re-connect it.  Typically this points to an `IFeatureclassName` for a featurelayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out that the COM object itelf has already be disposed of; only the metadata is available. Due to this, any attempt to re connect the IPropertySet causes a `E_FAIL`.

To avoid writing too much 'dumb' code, I have changed my approach to just have internal metadata look up, to find the Lyr file location on the hard disk. Once found from a `OpenFileDialog()`, I then re-added the layer to the existing Group Layer, if applicable.

The method is able to see if the 'source' to be added is of type `IFeatureLayer` or `IRasterLayer` and adds to the map using arcobjects.